# Bootstrap + AngularJS: custom menu behavior

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, menu

**EDIT:** added JSFiddle

I'm trying to build a menu or set of options whose (dynamic) details are coming from a server request. The data looks like this (unnecessary data was hidden):

```
{
    "name" : "root",
    "subOptions" : [{
            "name" : "A",
            "subOptions" : [{
                    "name" : "A1",
                }, {
                    "name" : "B1",
                }, {
                    "name" : "B3",
                }, {
                    "name" : "B4",
                }, {
                    "name" : "B5",
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name" : "B",
            "subOptions" : []
        }, {
            "name" : "C",
            "subOptions" : [{
                    "name" : "C1",
                }, {
                    "name" : "C1",
                }, {
                    "name" : "C3",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the Bootstrap 3 grid I simply tell how many columns each of these elements should have, and I don't have to worry where/when it will break to present the remaining elements in the lines below. My problem is related with the suboptions, which should be presented on a new line immediately below its parent:

[image: Desktop listing version]

When clicking the 'C' element, it should display its suboptions below it. The same should happen (for example) for the J element with its suboptions being presented below it.
If this grid was fixed for 6 elements per line, I'd probably be able to tell where is every parent and where the suboptions for each one of them should be displayed, but this grid must be responsive, meaning that at a certain point it'll have 4, 3 or 2 elements per line.

[image: Responsive listing version]

With all this variables I'm not able to manage the intended behavior.

I'm using Angular ng-repeat to loop through the options:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="option in object.options">
            <div class="container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-ms-8 col-xs-12">
                <div ng-click="selectOption(option)">
                    <div class="name"><span>{{option.name}}</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-ms-4 col-xs-4" ng-repeat="option in activeOption.suboptions">
                <button class="btn btn-lg" ng-click="selectSuboption(option)">{{ ::option.name }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way, the suboptions will always appear at the bottom of everything, which is not the desired behavior. So, the questions here are:

- is it possible to achieve this effect as dynamically as possible?
- how can I break the container to "inject" a row?

Sorry for the long post, but I'm trying to provide as much info as I can in order to solve a problem that's been consuming me for a few days now and can't seem to find a answer for it.

Here's a JSFiddle with my current implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/w5xrjhmd/6/

Comment: I am having a hard time using the code you gave to build out a test to confirm this but i think using ng-hide and ng-show you might be able to get what your looking for.  If you build a plunker or codepen I might be able to help more

Comment: How about positioning the sub options absolutely to fit in the gap? When the options wrap to the next line you could use some `CSS` to ensure a suitable gap is created.

Comment: Look into `ng-class`.  It will let you dynamically change the css class of your elements.

Comment: @user3271518: added a JSFiddle link.

Comment: @NunoM I really wanted to get your styling down but just ran out of time playing with it I hope the JS helps though

Answer (score 1):

With out spending too much time with styling this is what I came up with as a solution for your problem.  I hope it helps

Here it it on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXNRzZ?editors=101

```
<div ng-app="myAppModule" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="s in data">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class="{active: isActive(s)}" ng-click="select(s); showMe = !showMe">{{s.code}}</a>
      <a href="#" ng-show="showMe" ng-repeat="o in s.subOptions" class="btn btn-sm">{{o.code}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is just the AngularJS I am not including your data set or controller structure I didnt make any changes to it

```
  $scope.select = function(i) {
    $scope.selected = i;
  };
  $scope.isActive = function(item) {
    return $scope.selected === item;
  };
```

Here is the HTML for having it in your styling. I think/hope its right.

also here is it on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOYoEE?editors=101

```
<div ng-app="myAppModule" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-repeat="s in data" class="container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-ms-8 col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': isActive(s)}" ng-click="select(s); showMe = !showMe">{{s.code}}</button>
    <button href="#" ng-show="showMe" ng-repeat="o in s.subOptions" class="btn btn-sm">{{o.code}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help me. There's no responsive design, and somehow, each root element keeps on repeating (I think it's repeating the same number of root elements on the data list.
Bootstrap grid is also mandatory, since I'm using it to keep everything responsive, and you skipped it completely.
Still, thank you for your time on this issue.

Comment: sorry 1 to many ng-repeats....as for responsive design I can show you what happens if you use the columns....it becomes extra responsive lol one sec.

Comment: @NunoM ok check out my 2nd attempt

Comment: @NunoM got any feedback on the 2nd attempt?

Comment: user3271518, sorry for not replying, by the time you answered I had already left for the weekend. About your code, it's almost that, but the suboptions are not supposed to stack vertically. Could you please take a look at the pictures I have on the question. Wherever you are on the menu, suboptions should appear on a line below the selected option, but starting on the left and should fill the line (horizontally), breaking it when there's no more space left.